# Trying every letter/word combination possible in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to create a program, that will "create" a series of characters over and over, and compare them to a keyword (unknown to the user or computer). This is very similar to a "brute force" attack if you will, except this will logically build out every single letter it can.

The other thing, is that I've temporarily built this code to handle JUST 5 letter words, and have it broken out into a "value" 2D string array. I have this as a very temporary solution, to help logically discover what it is that my code is doing, before I throw it into super-dynamic and complex for-loops.

```
public class Sample{

static String key, keyword = "hello";
static String[] list = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","1","2","3","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
int keylen = 5; // Eventually, this will be thrown into a for-loop, to get dynamic "keyword" sizes. (Will test to every word, more/less than 5 characters eventually)

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] values = {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}; // More temporary hardcodes. If I can figure out the for loop, the rest can be set to dynamic values.

    int changeout_pos = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while(true){
        if (counter == list.length){ counter = 0; changeout_pos++; } // Swap out each letter we have in list, in every position once.

        // Try to swap them. (Try/catch is temporary lazy way of forcing the computer to say "we've gone through all possible combinations")
        try { values[changeout_pos] = list[counter]; } catch (Exception e) { break; } 

        // Add up all the values in their respectful positions. Again, will be dynamic (and in a for-loop) once figured out.
        key = values[0] + values[1] + values[2] + values[3] + values[4];
        System.out.println(key); // Temporarily print it.
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(keyword)){ break; } // If it matches our lovely keyword, then we're done. We've done it!

        counter ++; // Try another letter.
    }

    System.out.println("Done! \nThe keyword was: " + key); // Should return what "Keyword" is.
}
}
```

My goal is to have the output look like this: (For five letter example)

```
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
...
aaaba
aaabb
aaabc
aaabd
...
aabaa
aabab
aabac
...
```

So on and so forth. By running this code now however, it is not what I was hoping for. Now, it will go:

```
aaaaa
baaaa
caaaa
daaaa
... (through until 9)
9aaaa
9baaa
9caaa
9daaa
...
99aaa
99baa
99caa
99daa
... (Until it hits 99999 without finding the "keyword")
```

Any help appreciated. I'm really struggling to solve this puzzle.

Comment: Any reason you don't include "0" in the list of characters? If you did, there's a trick you could use with `Integer.toString(value, 36)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your alphabet is missing `0` (zero) and `z`. It also has `3` twice.

Second, the number of five letter words using 36 possible characters is 60,466,176. The equation is `(size of alphabet)^(length of word)`. In this case, that is `36^5`. I ran your code, and its only generating 176 permutations.

On my machine, with a basic implementation of five nested for loops, each iterating over the alphabet, it took 144 seconds to generate and print all the permutations. So, if you're getting quick results, you should check what's being generated.

Of course, manually nesting for loops isn't a valid solution for when you want the length of the word to be variable, so you still have some work to do. However, my advice would be to pay attention to the details and validate your assumptions!

Good luck.